# golang api request works in browser but return a 401 (Unauthorized) when requested from JavaScript running locally

Tags: javascript, http, go, cookies

I have a RESTful api built with golang running on port `3000`

When I navigate in my browser to `http://localhost:3000` I get a `200 (Success)`. The server also successfully sends me the JSON with a value from the server cookies.

However, when I try to `Fetch` the code from within my JavaScript SPA which is being run on port `8080`, I get a `401 (Unauthorized)` response. I also get a server error describing `http: named cookie not present`.

I've included a very stripped down version:

**myapp.js**

```
fetch("http://localhost:3000/authenticate")
    .then((r) => {
        return r;
    })
    .then((r) => {
        console.log(r)
    })
```

**server.go**

```
package main

// func respond(w http.ResponseWriter, value *string, status int)
// writes header and encoded json

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/authenticate", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
        cookie, err := r.Cookie("cookie_name")
        if err != nil {
            // here's where I get the server error
            fmt.Println(err)
            respond(w, nil, http.StatusTeapot)
            return
        }
        respond(w, cookie.Value, http.StatusOK)
    })
    c := cors.New(cors.Options{
        AllowedOrigins:   []string{"http://localhost:8080"},
        AllowCredentials: true,
    })
    handler := c.Handler(mux)
    http.ListenAndServe(":3000", handler)
}
```

I'm pretty sure it's not a CORS problem. In the example I just gave the error I get is `418 (I'm a teapot)` for demonstration purposes. The real problem seems to lie in the server error saying `http: named cookie not present`, even though when I look at the cookies at `http://localhost:3000` in my browser it's there.

My JavaScript SPA is being run with `webpack-dev-server` on port `8080`, so maybe that could be a source of the problem? That said I would really like to be able to test my app locally with webpack.

Why can't the server read the cookie when being requested from JavaScript?

Comment: you're not using and registering **c** the cors var `c := cors.New( ...` and you're using the default mux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have cross-domain cookies.

In your case, a cookie is stored on the browser side for site `localhost:8080`.
It is however not available when accessing `localhost:3000`.

A solution would be to serve your website with the same server, or use GET or POST parameters.

Comment: So when `localhost:client` fetch the server, `localhost:server`, the server is accessing the `localhost:client` url cookies? EDIT: I'm originally storing the cookie on the server url, and then trying to send that as JSON back to the client

Comment: When `localhost:server` is fetched, the server only has access to the `localhost:server` cookies, which are probably empty in your case. EDIT - In your console profiler, under the Network tab (might be called different for other than Chrome), you can see the request headers you are sending to the server. Try to inspect the cookies header.

Comment: **Host**:`localhost:server`
**Origin**:`http://localhost:client`
**Referer**:`http://localhost:client/`

Comment: (I'm not into web programming, so asking) could sending permissive CORS headers help somehow with this case?

Comment: Ok I did some more looking around and it turned out the go server was creates cookies at the referrer url. So if I called the server from the client app, it would make cookies for the client. If I called the server directly from the browser it would set the cookies for the server.